# Is it possible to play with Goro in Versus mode?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

In MK9 on Xbox, is it possible to unlock Goro or others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Game FAQs Cheats](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/961032-mortal-kombat/cheats) lists only Cyber Sub-Zero and Quan Chi as unlockable characters. Furthermore one of their most complete [FAQS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/961032-mortal-kombat/faqs/62469) for move lists does not show Goro as a playable character.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only play as Goro on Challenge Tower #150, on both the Xbox 360 and PS3 versions.